# Pulling a hyperlink to clipboard to paste in other locations

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink, copy-paste

I have 0 experience or knowledge with code.

I am trying to create a card for a wordpress blog post which has a quote.

The card has a button where a user can copy the quote directly to the clipboard.

I also want the hyperlink copied: (source) with the link attached to my site.

I keep running this code through GPT and rewriting. But every time it just copies the text and doesn't even try to copy the URL too.

I have attached the code below, hopefully someone can help as I am going crazy.

```
<style>
.card-box {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #0077B5;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
}

.quote {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.quote p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #333333;
}

.quote a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copy-to-clipboard {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.copy-btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0077B5;
  border: 2px solid #0077B5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.copy-btn i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.signature {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #777777;
}
</style>

<div class="card-box">
  <div class="quote">
    <p id="quoteText">Enter your quote or statistic here</p>
    <a id="sourceLink" href="https://www.example.com">Source</a>
  </div>
  <div class="copy-to-clipboard">
    <button class="copy-btn" onclick="copyToClipboard()"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Copy Stat</button>
  </div>
  <div class="signature">
    <p>Chad Wyatt</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function copyToClipboard() {
    const quote = document.querySelector('#quoteText').textContent;
    const sourceLink = document.querySelector('#sourceLink').getAttribute('href');
    const copiedText = `Quote: ${quote}\nSource: ${sourceLink}`;
    
    const tempTextArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    tempTextArea.value = copiedText;
    document.body.appendChild(tempTextArea);
    tempTextArea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(tempTextArea);
    
    alert('Quote with source link copied to clipboard!');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code here https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

Works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I appreciate it.
For some reason, it still only copies the text and doesn't carry the hyperlink over. This is the issue I keep having when pasting. It refuses to store the hyperlink in the clipboard. (I don't know whether it's even possible to have a hyperlink and text copied on the clipboard). 

I also tried force copying the URL as text, but when pasting, the text would be as 'plain text' and wouldn't convert to a hyperlink

Comment: @Chad I have modified it so that you'll see the source as a hyperlink on output. Let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: It seems to be copying the actual HTML now and pasting the whole thing :(

Comment: @chad weird, can you check your code again? This is what i see as the output - "Quote: Enter your quote or statistic here Source: https://www.example.com" with the source as hyperlink and clickable.

Comment: that's really strange. Yeah, I have tried in Gdocs, email, WordPress, everywhere I paste it comes out as code. Yet when I press the copy button it alerts at the top of the webpage saying Quote and Source Link is copied

Comment: wow, i was unaware you were looking to paste this into a word editor. Then  your actual code should work as is. I just copied the entire text and link and pasted into word, notepad, email etc. Works everywhere.

Comment: Ah sorry - I am pasting the code into a HTML block in Wordpress. Then when previewing the page, I am testing the copy button. I want users to be able to copy the quote and the link to paste wherever they need. That's why I was testing on documents etc. (Only the pasting of the actual text). Nothing I have tried will paste the link correctly